# Банкнот или банкнота?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В текстах мне попадались варианты и "банкнот", и "банкнота". По отношению к денежным купюрам обычно это слово употребляется только специалистами в области финансов, поэтому я не знаю, как правильно говорить: все-таки "банкнот" или "банкнота" и есть ли какая-то разница между этими понятиями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И то и другое верно. Ушаков считает равноправными вариантами, но рядом со словом банкнот есть помета "фин." - значит, финансисты употребляют в муж. роде, а в бытовом - как купюра, ассигнация - банкнота. У Зализняка в словаре нет профессионализмов, он даёт парадигму общеупотребительную - банкнота. В орфоэпическом словаре тоже две формы.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/2852/%D0

http://www.slovopedia.com/3/193/773013.html